# Converting HQL to Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

HQL I want to convert in the Criteria.

HQL

```
select com from News as news " +
            "join news.comments as com " +
            "where news.id = :id " +
            "order by com.addDate desc"
```

Criteria

```
    DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(News.class);
    criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(id));
    DetachedCriteria cComment = criteria.createCriteria("comments");
    cComment.addOrder(Order.desc("addDate"));
    List<Comment> list = (List<Comment>)findByCriteria(cComment, false);
```

Criteria is working, but returned list News. I want to return the Сomments. Please help me?

Answer (score 1):

try this may help you:

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(News.class);
criteria.setProjection( Projections.property("com"), "com"));
criteria.add(Restrictions.idEq(id));
DetachedCriteria cComment = criteria.createCriteria("comments");
cComment.addOrder(Order.desc("addDate"));
List<String> list = (List<String>)findByCriteria(cComment, false);
```